# XSLT transform attributes from node to elements of another node and remove them from source node

Tags: xslt, saxon

given this xml

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog                    
                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
  <changeSet author="system (generated)"
           context="legacy"
           id="1537289247911-1"
           objectQuotingStrategy="LEGACY">
    <createTable remarks="Language-dependent texts."
                 tableName="AS_LANGUAGETEXT">
      <column name="TEXTID" remarks="Description identifier" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_AS_LANGUAGETEXT"/>
      </column>
      <column name="LANGID"
                remarks="Language identifier"
                type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR(2 ${byteVarcharType})">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_AS_LANGUAGETEXT"/>
      </column>
      <column name="TEXT"
                remarks="Description"
                type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR(4000 ${charVarcharType})"/>
    </createTable>
    <customChange>
      ...
    </customChange>
  </changeSet>
  <changeSet>
    <createTable>
      ...
    </createTable>
    <customChange>
      ...
    </customChange>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I would like to:

- from source `changeset/createTable` remove `@remarks` and move it to target `changeSet/setTableRemarks` and also copy `@tableName` from source to target
- from source `changeset/createTable/column` remove `@remarks` and move it to target `changeSet/setColumnRemarks` and also copy `@tableName` `@columnName` from source to target
- if possible generate `@id` with UUID in new changeSet
- if possible add newly created changeSet after currently modified changeSet

so at the end it should look like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog  http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
  <changeSet author="system (generated)"
           context="legacy"
           id="1537289247911-1"
           objectQuotingStrategy="LEGACY">
    <createTable tableName="AS_LANGUAGETEXT">
      <column name="TEXTID" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_AS_LANGUAGETEXT"/>
      </column>
      <column name="LANGID"
                type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR(2 ${byteVarcharType})">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_AS_LANGUAGETEXT"/>
      </column>
      <column name="TEXT"
                type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR(4000 ${charVarcharType})"/>
    </createTable>
    <customChange>
      ...
    </customChange>
  </changeSet>
  <changeSet id="621c99b7-eb65-462b-890c-014079e5b44c" author="system">
    <setTableRemarks tableName="AS_LANGUAGETEXT" remarks="Language-dependent texts." />
    <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_LANGUAGETEXT" columnName="TEXTID" remarks="Description identifier" />
    <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_LANGUAGETEXT" columnName="LANGID" remarks="Language identifier" />
    <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_LANGUAGETEXT" columnName="LANGID" remarks="Description" />
  </changeSet>
  <changeSet>
    <createTable>
      ...
    </createTable>
    <customChange>
      ...
    </customChange>
  </changeSet>
  <changeSet>
    <setTableRemarks ... />
    <setColumnRemarks ... />
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**EDIT:** I did it with this template. Only what I don't know how to do is the uuid because saxon-he doesn't support calls to java. So instead of uuid I've used `generate-id()` function.

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
               xpath-default-namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="changeSet[createTable]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="createTable"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::createTable)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="changeSet" namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
            <xsl:attribute name="id" select="generate-id()" />
            <xsl:attribute name="author">system</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="setTableRemarks" namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
                <xsl:attribute name="tableName" select="createTable//@tableName"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="remarks" select="createTable//@remarks"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:for-each select="createTable/column">
                <xsl:element name="setColumnRemarks" namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
                    <xsl:attribute name="tableName" select="../@tableName"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="columnName" select="@name"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="remarks" select="@remarks"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="createTable/@remarks"/>
    <xsl:template match="createTable/column/@remarks"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

For transformations I'm using `Saxon-HE:9.8.0-12` (java)

Comment: Unless you need to dynamically generate names, it's generally better to use the literal element/attribute constructors, and if you want to propagate an attribute, instead of re-defining them, just copy them. It makes it easier to read and maintain. i.e. at the top of your stylesheet, declare the default namespace: `xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"` and then you can change your templates to: `<changeSet author="system id="{generate-id()}"><setTableRemarks><xsl:copy-of select="createTable//(@tableName,@remarks)"/>`

Comment: @MadsHansen, as I can't comment on the answer you have deleted, I am using the comment here to continue that discussion: as far as I have tested, for instance with https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQW/1, Saxon HE only supports the two `exsl:node-set` and `exsl:object-type` function, not any of the `math` functions.

Comment: @MadsHansen, but your suggestion to use that stylesheet you linked to does work with Saxon HE as it doesn't rely on the XSLT processor to support the EXSLT `math:power` function, instead it implements it in XSLT itself (https://gist.github.com/azinneera/778f69ae6b0049b5edcd69da70072405#file-uuid-gen-xslt-L77). So your suggestion can be used with Saxon HE. Only that attempt in that linked stylesheet to implement the EXSLT `math:power` function is not needed as Saxon (including HE) supports the XPath `math:pow` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-math-pow.

Answer (score 0):

UUID can be implemented in XSLT.

For example, it has been implemented in this stylesheet: https://gist.github.com/azinneera/778f69ae6b0049b5edcd69da70072405, which you can include or import and then use it's `uuid:get-uuid()` method.

Assuming that it was saved locally as `uuid-gen.xsl`, applied to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:uuid="http://www.uuid.org" 
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:include href="uuid-gen.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="changeSet[createTable]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="createTable"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::createTable)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <changeSet id="{uuid:get-uuid(.)}" author="system">
            <setTableRemarks>
                <xsl:copy-of select="createTable//(@tableName,@remarks)"/>
            </setTableRemarks>
            <xsl:for-each select="createTable/column">
                <setColumnRemarks>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../@tableName"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="columnName" select="@name"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@remarks"/>
                </setColumnRemarks>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </changeSet>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="createTable/@remarks"/>
    <xsl:template match="createTable/column/@remarks"/>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "Saxon HE does support EXSLT": is that true? That linked stylesheet tries to implement an EXSLT `math` function in XSLT 2, it doesn't rely on the XSLT processor to support. Saxon HE supports the standard XPath `math` functions from the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math/`, documented at that URL https://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math/. So it shouldn't be necessary to rely on EXSLT, nor to try to implement a `power` function.

Comment: Darn, I thought that it did. I thought that I had selected HE when I tested in oXygen, but either didn’t or it still works when maybe it shouldn’t. https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/functions/exslt.html